# Azure function of queueing to service bus over million record does not reach to the end

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions

I'm trying to implement a solution that runs periodically (once in a week) and calls to an external api with 1,500,000 items metadata `{{domain}}/items`, then trying to figure out for each of the items if it needs to be updated or inserted to the database according by some arbitrary logic.

After several [attempts](https://shokrano.medium.com/implementing-azure-functions-with-storage-queue-6b70fad5f58e) I've ended up with implementing a service bus solution with two azure function (one for enqueueing and the other for dequeuing).

The first azure function triggers periodically and calls the external api for 1.5 millions item's metadata (a Premium plan) - **every item is ~ 1.9 KB**:

```
[FunctionName("EnqueueFooMetadata")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
[ServiceBus("foosmetadata", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] IAsyncCollector<FooMetadata> foosMetadataQueue)
{
    IEnumerable<FooMetadata> foosMetadata = await _service.GetFoosMetadata();

    this._logger.LogTrace($"Start Enqueue {foosMetadata.Count()}");
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(foosMetadata, new ParallelOptions() { }, async (FooMetadata fooMetadata) =>
        {
            await foosMetadataQueue.AddAsync(fooMetadata);
        });
    });
    this._logger.LogTrace($"Done Enqueue {foosMetadata.Count()}");
}
```

And on the other side of the service bus there is a function that binds to it:

```
[FunctionName("DequeueGiataProperties")]
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("foosmetadata", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] FooMetadata foo)
{
    var getGiataProperiesResult = await _service.Dequeue(foo);

    this._logger.LogTrace($"dequeing item: {foo.Id}, was done successfully.");
}
```

It works as expected for a small amounts of items (when the count of `foosMetadata` in `IEnumerable<FooMetadata> foosMetadata = await _service.GetFoosMetadata();` is about 15,000), and I can see the trace of `Done Enqueue...`, but for larger amounts of items its always stops somewhere in the middle and I can not see the the trace.

I don't want to divert the suggested answers but it looks like a timeout issue with azure function. **any suggestion handling the big data issue**?

Comment: When it doesn't work, _how_ does it not work?

Comment: Hey @mjwills see updated question: and I can see the trace of Done Enqueue..., but for larger amounts of items its always stops somewhere in the middle and I can not see the the trace.

Comment: What is the limit on your Azure function execution time? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/blob/main/functions-premium-plan/overview.md When it _stops working_ how long is it taking (i.e. roughly how long is "too long")?

Comment: One option could be that the async collector is aggressively batching and it's too much. An alternative would be to try and send one message at a time and see how many out of 1.5mil make it through with non async collector. I'd also get rid of the task.run and parallel. Give it a try.

Comment: `_service.GetFoosMetadata()` always return 1.5M items?

Comment: Hey @ChetanRanpariya In reality this code has a request parameter, but for the sake of brevity I've omitted the request, when the `GetFoosMetadata()` returns only few thousands it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having 1.5 million items to be converted to messages in a single function call sounds like the culprit here. The aforementioned parallel `foreach` along with `Task.Run` doesn't help either. Combined with the batching `IAsyncCollector` and no wonder it gets stalled. Likely the issue here is also the overall size of the messages that are attempted to be sent out and the underlying implementation in Functions SDK. With 60 bytes per item, and let's take on average another 40 bytes of overhead (headers, system properties, AMQP extras), that would be 150,000,000 bytes or 143 MB.

What I'd suggest are the following few options:

1. *If* possible, reduce the number of items returned from the call.
2. *Otherwise*, split the batch into smaller chunks and send those chunks as a few messages. This will also improve the reliability as your HTTP request will end up being converted into a series of messages that will be reliably processed.

Another option is to investigate flushing `IAsyncCollector` to force it to send smaller batches. If not possible, use your own message sender. Finally, as you're using in-process SDK, you could leverage the preview of the Service Bus Functions extensions (`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus`) that is almost out of preview and is currently at 5.0.0-beta.5. With this version, you'll be able to use Azure Service Bus's latest SDK with safe batching built-in (`ServiceBusMessageBatch`).

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a number of issues going on there and most of them are in the publisher portion of the code.

1. Parallel.Foreeach is not asynchronous, the compiler allows you to
   write asyc code, but Parrallel.ForEach is actually a synchronous
   feature. You'r using async lambas in the Parallel.ForEach which will
   have unexpected behaviour.
2. Second issue is likely a timeout issue on your Azure function.
   Depending on the plan you have at most 5 (minutes on a Consumption
   Plan) and (20 minutes on a Paid Plan) for you function to complete.
   Calling an API in 1.5Million times you have an expectation that it
   will complete in that time frame, it's quite probably that the
   overhead of even 1/10 of a second calling the API, is breaking the
   timing limits.

There are a number of ways to break the Parallel.ForeEach, the main being to switch to using a Task based parallel mechanism in conjunction with something like DataFlow ActionBlock.

The timing issue is likely harder to solve give the quantity of API calls you are making, BUT

1. Service bus supports batching when adding messages, where you can
   add multiple messages to a queue at once, you mention you are on a
   premium plan, that allows  multiple messages up to 1M in size be
   posted to Service bus at once. This simple change may give you
   sufficient performce to get all you messages published.

Without a fully working code example and samples of message sizes it's difficult to give definitive answers to the questions you are asking.
I would therefore suggest that you provide a complete working example to help others try and resolve the issues you are facing.